# Find application version code in Kotlin Multiplatform Moblie

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I want to find application version code in Kmm. In specific platform i.e.

**Android**

```
var versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

it will return `1.1`

**iOS**

```
let appVersion = "iOS " + (Bundle.main.versionNumber ?? "")
```

it will return `1.1`

How can I do in Kmm in specific platform?

**UPDATE**

I tried **expect/actual** but I am getting some error.

**CommonMain**

```
expect class Platform() {
    val versionCode: String
}
```

**iosMain**

```
actual class Platform actual constructor() {
    actual val versionCode =
        platform.Foundation.NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary?.get("CFBundleVersion")
}
```

**Error on iOS side**

[image]

**androidMain**

```
actual class Platform actual constructor() {
    actual val versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
}
```

**Error on android side**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KMM doesn't have some built in support for such feature.

One option is to create an `expect` function and apply platform-specific code in `actual` for each platform.

I used to sync app version with module version, but if you can't do that, you can create `Platform` in your app module and pass it to your common module:

Common main:

```
expect class Platform { // remove constructor here
    val versionCode: String
}
```

Android main:

```
actual class Platform(actual val versionCode: String)
```

Then in app module you just create it `Platform(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.toString())` and pass it into your shared module depending on your architecture.

---

Another option is to use [BuildKonfig](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig) plugin: it will generate a configuration file like the Android plugin does, depending on what you specify in the `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
buildkonfig {
    packageName = "com.example.app"

    defaultConfigs {
        buildConfigField(STRING, "VERSION_CODE", "1.0")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
com.example.app.BuildKonfig.VERSION_CODE
```

Comment: thanks for replying to me. I'll go to expect/actual because both platform have different versions code. I tried some code with the help of actual/expect. Can you please guide me ? I update me code. please have a look

Comment: @vivekmodi  First image is just says that there's an error in one of actual declarations, which is the second fine. if you have `import com.your.module.BuildConfig` in your android file, try building it - I've faced IDE bug that shows such error.

Comment: I need my app BuildConfig value not from module.

Comment: @vivekmodi In this case, I think the only way is to pass it through a parameter of interface implementation - you don't have access to the App from other modules. In fact I set up gradle so that all modules have the same version as the application itself.

Comment: Can you give me example please or any reference ?

Answer (score 0):

I would only use `expect/actual` if you want the `shared` module/framework version.

If you're building a KMM app, however, I'd suspect that the version you need is the app version instead, not the `shared` module's version.

I'd go with an `AppConfig` interface/protocol, something like:

```
interface AppConfig {
    val version: String
}
```

Then provide the `IosAppConfig` and `AndroidAppConfig` implementations from your `androidApp` and `iosApp`.

Comment: Yes I want value in kmm androidMain